# Limit amount of articles with a loop

Tags: pug, wintersmith

On my index page I wanna give out two seperate lists of articles (I wouldn't mind using the pagination plugin by the way), and I want to list the last 5 in each "category". But I have no idea how I can count up in the loop.

I already tried

```
#{news-loop} = #{news-loop} + 1
```

but that did not work.

```
- var news-loop = 0
block content
  section.work.index
    h2 Arbeiten
    a.archive(href='/arbeiten') Übersicht
    ul
      each article in articles
        if article.metadata.work
          li
            h3
              a(href=article.url)= article.title
```

Answer (score 1):

Normal Jade [iteration](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/) should accomplish this. The issue with your code is you cannot have hyphens in variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You could limit the amount of elements passed to the `each` loop:

`each article in articles.slice(0, 5)`

however it seems to me this kind of data processing should better happen before the view is generated.